# How do I use javascript correctly in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to list vids from an array in my React component:

```
class ListVids extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let vid = '' ;
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.vids.length === 0){
      return <p></p>
    } else {
    return (
      <div>
       <ul>
       this.state.vids.map(function (vid) {
         <li key={vid.id.toString()}>{vid.id}</li>
       }
       )
       </ul>
      </div>
     );
    }
  }
}
```

But I got the error: `'vid' is not defined  no-undef.` Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any JavaScript expression inside JSX must be wrapped in `{ … }` to signify an inline JSX expression. Since your `Array#map` is an expression that returns an array of JSX elements, you have to wrap it in `{ … }`:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    {
      this.state.vids.map(function(vid) {
        <li key={vid.id.toString()}>{vid.id}</li>
      })
    }
  </ul>
</div>
```

See [Embedding Expressions in JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx) at the React Documentation.

---

Your old code is actually contains a syntax error. The reason you get the error that `vid` is not defined is because ESLint preprocesses and statically analyzes your code for errors such as variables that are not defined *before* Babel transpiles your JSX to JavaScript and sees the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew Li!